# Key-Value databases that support timestamp-based querying?

Tags: cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, bigtable

When I worked at Google, I used a Bigtable a lot, and ever since I left I've been missing it. One of the nice things about Bigtable is that its data model had time-based versioning built in. In other words, your key structure was:

```
(row:string, column:string, time:int64) -> string
```

This meant that when you issued a query against bt, you could get the most recent value, and you usually would. *But* you could also transparently wind the clock back to a specific timestamp. This is especially useful for tasks which involve repeatedly processing the same key:column combo.

Does any technology out there support the same timestamp-based data model? I see plenty of similar technologies that support extremely scalable `key:column, value` lookups, but I can't seem to find any support for this sort of time-based rewind feature.

Answer (score 1):

I believe DynamoDB can satisfy your need here. It supports two different kinds of keys. The second one below is the one you'd want to use.

- Partition key – A simple primary key, consists of a single attribute.
- Partition key and sort key – Referred to as a **composite primary key**, which is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is the partition key (`PK`), and the second attribute is the sort key (`SK`).

The PK value is used as input to an internal hash function which determines the partition (physical storage internal to DynamoDB) where a record will be stored. All records with the same PK value are stored together, in sorted order by SK value.

Therefore, for your scenario you would set your SK as number attribute and populate it with timestamps. This will allow you to write efficient queries using the mathematical operators (`<`, `>`) and the `between` operator.